# WPF Check Box binding IsChecked to User Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, binding, application-settings

I have list of checkboxes. The Content binding works fine.
I have a list of Settings in the Application Settings of type bool.
My question, how to bind IsChecked to these Settings ?

Please note that the list of check-boxes is dynamically generated from a static list on a database table. In my case there are 7 check-boxes that I need to bind to 7 different settings.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
 <ListBox Name="CheckBoxZone" ItemsSource="{Binding mySourceProperty}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone"  Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChkd}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Please supply the structure of your `Settings` class. What are the types of `Ischkd`? You code looks ok. What is going wrong? Please don't reply __It doesn't work__. Details details details.

Comment: I don't have a settings class. To be honest I don't know how to proceed from this point.

Comment: Sorry I am going to vote for close. You need to learn how to do some C# programming and do some WPF tutorials. You don't seem to be sure what you are asking. If you have not created a class with a 'IsChkd' field you are a long way from getting anything working. Two links for you [learn c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx) and [learn WPF](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsChkd, 
                Mode=TwoWay, 
                Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

where 
            `xmlns:p="clr-<yourProjectNamespace>.Properties"`

And don't forget to Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Comment: Hey Madenis, I have many checkboxes, how it is going to figure out which checkbox IsChecked to bind to which user setting ?

Comment: You make a different bool setting and a different binding?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, IsChkd is a property that I have not implemented. it is there just for code view.